# Add Custom Class on Controls during rendering for Nette Forms

Tags: php, nette

I am using this example [Bootstrap3 example](https://github.com/nette/forms/blob/master/examples/bootstrap3-rendering.php#L60) to render a form and was wondering if it was possible to add custom classnames to form input wrappers based on the control type. I tried the following but it applies to the form inputs and not the surrounding wrapper divs (form-group in this case):

```
foreach ($form->getControls() as $control) {
    $type = $control->getOption('type');
    $control->getControlPrototype()->addClass('form-' . $control->getControlPrototype()->type);
}
```

Comment: Better is to use some renderer. See https://github.com/nextras/forms/blob/master/src/Rendering/Bs3FormRenderer.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input wrapper is not a concern of the *Control* (input) but of the *Renderer*. `DefaultFormRenderer` wraps the control in the [`renderPair`](https://api.nette.org/2.3.8/source-Forms.Rendering.DefaultFormRenderer.php.html#343-360) method – other renderers do not even have to do any wrapping. For that reason you can not get the wrapper’s prototype.

You can use [`$control->setOption('class', …)`](https://api.nette.org/2.3.8/Nette.Forms.Controls.BaseControl.html#_setOption), though, and `DefaultFormRenderer` will use it as a class for the wrapper (as you can see in the source of `DefaultFormRenderer::renderPair`).

Rather than manipulate the the form directly, it is much cleaner to implement a custom [`IFormRenderer`](https://api.nette.org/2.3.8/Nette.Forms.IFormRenderer.html) as @hrach mentions above. His [Bs3FormRenderer](https://github.com/nextras/forms/blob/master/src/Rendering/Bs3FormRenderer.php) is a nice example.

Comment: Or you can call $control->setAttribute('class', 'your-class');

Comment: @John That is not what OP was asking for. [`setAttribute`](https://api.nette.org/2.3.8/Nette.Forms.Controls.BaseControl.html#_setAttribute) refers to control itself (i.e. the input), not the wrapper.